# JSP Integer.parseInt

Tags: jsp

I am trying to convert a String to Integer in JSP page. I get runtime errors while converting. `temp[0]` is perfectly displaying 5 when I remove the 2 lines under it. Here's my sample code:

```
<%@ page import = "java.util.*"%>
<%@ page import = "java.lang.*"%>
<% String name = "5.ACC";
   String temp[] = name.split("\\.");
   out.println(temp[0]); 
   int id = Integer.parseInt(temp[0]);
   out.println(id);
%>
```

Comment: I've just tested the code and it works fine in my JSP.

Comment: Can you post your runtime exceptions?

Comment: -1: can you provide more information?

Answer (score 0):

With this information. Feel that you can use  temp[0]·trim() to avoid the number format exception.